# RedisError: Redis connection needs to be open

Tags: redis

I'm using redis-om with nodejs and I'm facing error !!

> **RedisError: Redis connection needs to be open**

When I try to divide the app logic into **controllers**, **routers**it gets crashed , But it works completely fine if I make all the api's and endpoint in the main file (server.js) !!

The controller file's code :

[image: This is controller file !!]

Connection file to redis :
[image: Connection file]

The actual error !!
[image: Actual error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller code has no opening of the redis client , you are only create a new client and then call it before opening it ,error is coming from the line

```
redisClient.fetchRepository(codeSchema)
```

here you are trying to use redis client before opening it

Have the file connecting redis client  right after line 4

1. the process is create new redis client - done on line 4
2. call open on the client (not done on the controller thus error)
3. Use the client to fetch etc

Below will work

```
const redisClient = new Client()
await redisClient.open('redis://localhost:6379')
```

then call

```
redisClient.fetchRepository(codeSchema)
```